Ory keto authorization model - transitive check definiton
I have started with the Ory Keto implementation. I have started with basic functionalities as creating tuples and checking the permission for the users base od the JWT authorization.
The basics works fine. So I decided to model more usable situation with Authorization model.
My plan is to have some sort of the hiearchy between the USERS. There is no hiearchy between the RESOURCES.
Desired functionality:
I have two users, one of them is the manager and the other is subordinate. If I am the manager, I have permission to see all the resources that my subordinate owns.
Model:
user1  ---> owner of the resource1 (has both edit and view permission)
user2 ---> manager of the user1 (has no direct relation to the resources1)
Here is the authorization model: (in OPL language)
import {Context, SubjectSet, Namespace} from "@ory/keto-namespace-types"

class User implements Namespace {
    related: {
        manager: User[]
    }

    permits = {        // Extra method to check if the subject is the manager of the object
        isManager: (ctx: Context): boolean => this.related.manager.includes(ctx.subject)  
    }
}

class Resource implements Namespace {
    related: {
        viewers: User[]
        editors: User[]
        parents: Resource[]
        owners: User[]
    }

    permits = {
        view: (ctx: Context): boolean =>
            this.related.viewers.includes(ctx.subject) ||
            this.related.parents.traverse((p) => p.permits.view(ctx)) ||
            this.permits.edit(ctx) ||
            this.related.owners.traverse((owner) =>
owner.related.manager.includes(ctx.subject)) ||
            this.related.owners.traverse((owner) => owner.permits.isManager(ctx)),
        edit: (ctx: Context) =>
            this.related.owners.includes(ctx.subject) ||
            this.related.editors.includes(ctx.subject) ||
            this.related.parents.traverse((p) => p.permits.edit(ctx)),
    }
}

Relation tuples
Resource:resource1#owners@user1     // user1 is owner of the resource1 
User:user1#manager@user2            // user 2 is the manager of the user 1

Expected behavour:
According to the authorization model. Following method should iterate over the owners of the resource1  (there should be only one User object => user1)
And for each owner there should be yet another iteration over the array of manager. ( this shoud be link between user2 and user1)
Second method is only attempt. With exactly the same functionality
this.related.owners.traverse((owner) => owner.related.manager.includes(ctx.subject)) ||
this.related.owners.traverse((owner) => owner.permits.isManager(ctx)),

Result:
Access is denied for the user2 (manager of the user1) to the resource1.
When I check with permissionAPI
user2 is manager of user1 => true
user 1 is owner of the resource1 => true
What I tried:
I have assigned different relation tuples where I have assigned the user2 not directly as subject, but as subject set
User:user1#manager@(User:user2) 

Question:
According to the issue I have, I am not sure if I managed to grasp how to write the  authorization model and following permissions.
I would be very happy if someone could clarify to me, if I am missing something or just not getting the whole concept correctly.
Or how I should proceed with debuging of the issue.
Any help is welcome and appreciated :)
Thank you
----------
Configs below
Keto.yaml
log:
  level: trace
  format: json
  leak_sensitive_values: true

limit:
  max_read_depth: 100

serve:
  read:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 4466
  write:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 4467

namespaces: 
  location: file:///home/ory/namespaces.keto.ts

Docker compose.yml
 keto-migration:
    image: oryd/keto:latest
    command: migrate up -y -c /home/ory/keto.yml
    restart: no
    environment:
      DSN: postgres://keto:keto@postgres:5432/keto
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: keto/.
        target: /home/ory
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

  keto:
    image: oryd/keto:latest
    ports:
      - "4466:4466"
      - "4467:4467"
    command: serve -c /home/ory/keto.yml
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      DSN: postgres://keto:keto@postgres:5432/keto
      LOG_LEAK_SENSITIVE_VALUES: true
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: keto/.
        target: /home/ory
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
      keto-migration:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

